# getAttribute() is not returning complete value in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I am testing using protractor to test my web application. When I am trying to extract an attribute value using getAttribute(), it is not returning complete value. Part to character towards the end of the value is missing. For example:

html:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg cip__attached" href="http://www.testool.net/?hsdgfshdgfsdhf&dh=fgshdfgsfd&sdfgjs=sdfnsdfsfdj&usdfjs=dhfh&asd=23423423478" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Hello</a>
```

protractor test:

```
browser.findElement(by.tagName('a')).
 getAttribute('href').
   then(function(attr){
     console.log(attr);         
       });
```

Console log:

its displaying only
http://www.testool.net/?hsdgfshdgfsdhf&dh=fgshdfgsfd&sdfgjs=sdfnsdfsfdj&usdfjs=dhfh&

somehow the last part of the text is missing which **asd=23423423478**

Does anyone have this issue?
thanks

Comment: In protractor you should use browser.manage().logs().get('browser') does this display the expected output?

Comment: Can you try getting the outerHTML of that element, just for debugging to see if the full href is in that?

Comment: can you share the link?